# What is the difference between Master Node and Control Plane on Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

What is the difference between Master Node and Control Plane?

Is the same or is there any difference?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have a look at https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.20.md#urgent-upgrade-notes . This should answer your Question:

- **The label applied to control-plane nodes "node-role.kubernetes.io/master" is now deprecated and will be removed in a future release after a GA deprecation period.**
- **Introduce a new label "node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane" that will be applied in parallel to "node-role.kubernetes.io/master" until the removal of the "node-role.kubernetes.io/master" label.**

I think also important is this:

- Make "kubeadm upgrade apply" add the "node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane" label on existing nodes that only have the "node-role.kubernetes.io/master" label during upgrade.
- Please adapt your tooling built on top of kubeadm to use the "node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane" label.
- The taint applied to control-plane nodes "node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule" is now deprecated and will be removed in a future release after a GA deprecation period.
- Apply toleration for a new, future taint "node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane:NoSchedule" to the kubeadm CoreDNS / kube-dns managed manifests. Note that this taint is not yet applied to kubeadm control-plane nodes.
- Please adapt your workloads to tolerate the same future taint preemptively.

Answer (score 11):

Same thing, we switched to the "control plane" terminology about a year ago as it is more accurate and doesn't have problematic cultural undertones.

Comment: I imagined something like that but I could not confirm it ... So now, i can't use the term "Master Node", right? Do the worker Nodes, still have the same terminology?

Comment: Master Nodes will be part of Control Plane, but again it is just a change in terminology and Worker nodes still have same terminology.  Please see https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/ to know more.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! i will check it!!!

Answer (score 7):

Control Plane hosts important components like api-server,etcd,kube-scheduler and kube-controller in your kubernetes cluster. As said, it is same as Master Node just a terminology change pretty lately.

Comment: ok.. i have a project about Kubernetes and i have to write about that.. So i want to be sure for this change.. You helped me a lot!! Thank you so much!!